# How can I pipe a GitHub CLI command into an xargs Git command?

Tags: json, git, github, xargs

**Background**: I file pull requests to an upstream repo which I’m not a maintainer of. I want to delete my local and remote branches from which I filed those PRs and which have been merged/closed. I want to do this in one swoop from the terminal.

**Steps taken**: I use the GitHub CLI to check which of my branches have been merged/closed upstream, for example, with `gh pr list -A author -s merged --json 'headRefName'`. Then I pipe this into `jq -r '.[].headRefName'` in order to get a list of branch names that have been merged.

One result of running the command is: **patch-36**

But when I pipe these results into `xargs git branch -d`, I get: **error: branch 'patch-36?' not found.** The problem seems to be that a question mark is being inserted with the last piping.

**Goal**: How can I prevent the question mark being added to the input of `xargs git branch -d`?

Output of `cat -t`: **patch-36^M**

**OS**: Windows 10

**Terminal**: Powershell & Git Bash

Comment: To debug pipe into [`cat -t`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/cat)

Comment: Git Bash output: **patch-36^M**; Powershell errors out with **Parameter cannot be processed because the parameter name 't' is ambiguous.**

Comment: As you can see from the output of `cat -t`, the problem is not a question mark, it's a `^M` (carriage return) character. In theory if you just filter the output from `jq` through `tr -d '\n'` you should be in good shape.

Comment: @larsks I tried:  **gh pr list -A ConsciousClay -s merged --json 'headRefName' | jq -r '.[].headRefName' | tr -d '\n' | cat -t** and I got: **patch-38^Mpatch-36^M**

Comment: Right, because when I wrote `'\n'` I meant of course `'\r'`, which is a carriage return . `\n` is a linefeed. Sorry about that.

Comment: That did it. Thanks!